# Deleting Two Columns Simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

The following code deletes Column J only:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("J:J").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) _
        = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("L:L").SpecialCells( _
        xlCellTypeVisible)) Then

    Columns("J:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'instead of .Select and Selection.

End If
```

However, I would like to delete both columns `J` and `L` at the same time. How can I do this?

Comment: `Range("L:L,J:J").Delete` will work.  This is the kind of thing that you can learn from recording a macro.   You should watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily modify your current code using `Union()`.

Change this line:

```
Columns("J:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'instead of .Select and Selection.
```

to this

```
Union(Columns("J"), Columns("L")).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

This will take both ranges and delete them simultaneously.

Your code block should now look as follows:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("J:J").SpecialCells( _
        xlCellTypeVisible)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
        Range("L:L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) Then

    Union(Columns("J"), Columns("L")).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End If
```

---

I would also add that it would be a good idea to make sure you are deleting the columns *in the correct worksheet*. Please be explicit and always qualify your range with at the very least your worksheet, your workbook wouldn't be a bad idea too:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("J:J").SpecialCells( _
            xlCellTypeVisible)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
            .Range("L:L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) Then

        Union(.Columns("J"), .Columns("L")).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    End If

End With
```

Where you would replace the `1` in `Worksheets(1)` to either the:

- Correct worksheet index number, or
- The **name** of the worksheet, surrounded by double-quotes *(ex. `.Worksheets("Sheet1")`)*

Comment: Weird...it did not work but no error message either.

Comment: It did for me. Did you use the code block containing the `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` statement? Because you may have just deleted the wrong columns from another worksheet if you didn't read the two bullet points under that code block I posted and made the adjustments I recommended.

Comment: I dont really get your first line "With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)"

Comment: Without using it. I have a "compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference"

Comment: So you still haven't read the two bullet points under the code block; I will update my answer - just tell me what is the [**complete name** of the worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WZyS.png) you are using this code on?

Comment: Ok, @cheesengng I updated my answer to show the unqualified route to take on this. See **the first code block** (the one without the `With ThisWorkbook...` in it. If you later decide to provide your worksheet name, I will edit that in as well to the 2nd code block.

Comment: I would ask, if the Sum of each column is equal to the other column.

Comment: @GMalc I would like to delete both column if the sum of both the same amount.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs , Thank you for the amended code. It work as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EVALUATE and [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) to check if the sums in the two columns match:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    With ws      'Your sheet name goes here
        If .Evaluate("AGGREGATE(9,3,J:J)") = .Evaluate("AGGREGATE(9,3,L:L)") Then
            Union(.Columns("J"), .Columns("L")).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The first argument passed to AGGREGATE is `Function_num` . `9` is `SUM`. The second argument is `Options`. `3` is `Ignore hidden rows, error values, nested SUBTOTAL and AGGREGATE functions`. The advantage of using AGGREGATE is you can specify different options for the sum conditions e.g. ignore errors as well as hidden rows.

---

Edit:

If using in a loop over worksheets use your worksheet variable from the loop in the With statement to ensure your ranges have a parent sheet specified. It will make your code less bug prone.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Evaluate("AGGREGATE(9,3,J:J)") = .Evaluate("AGGREGATE(9,3,L:L)") Then
                Union(.Columns("J"), .Columns("L")).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using your code but it shows error 'Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: Did you change the sheet name appropriately?

Comment: I did not, as I need the code to be generic so I can use it for next wksht. 
Anyway it's resolved already. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries but I will mention that you should mention info like that in the question. Also, you can be "generic" and accurate. If you rely on activesheet references by not using a parent sheet then you are leaving yourself wide open to bugs. If you are looping sheets then simply use your worksheet variable in the loop as the parent. For Each ws in .... With ws...... then your code is more robust.

Comment: Thanks for your teaching, I will definitely look into this in the near future. As I just started learn VBA and Macro, I just hope to make the code work so I can understand the basic.